# Casting function to another with different number of parameters in C

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers, cpython

In the [C/Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html), I found this.

First, the definition of a function:

```
static PyObject *
keywdarg_parrot(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *keywds)
{
    // Some code here.
}
```

Then, a casting like this:

```
(PyCFunction)(void(*)(void))keywdarg_parrot
```

where, quote:

> `PyCFunction` values only take two `PyObject*` parameters, and `keywdarg_parrot()` takes three.

Three questions for this casting:

1. How can one function be cast to another with fewer parameters? I mean, what happens with the extra parameters?
2. Why the casting of the arguments of `keywdarg_parrot` to `void(*)(void)`?

Comment: Why did you tag this C++?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a function pointer to a function pointer of a different type, but you have to cast it back if you want to call it. As long as it is just to store the function pointer or pass it around, there's no problem.

In this case, the cast is necessary to store the function pointer in the `PyMethodDef` structure. That structure also contains a field which identifies the calling convention used by the function; in this case, the function is marked as `METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS`, where the `METH_KEYWORDS` flag promises that the function takes three arguments.

This is explained in section 1.4 of the same document you link.

I have no explanation for the intermediate cast. It looks like someone reasoning by analogy with an intermediate cast to `void*` for pointer casts, only necessary in C++. But afaik, C++ does not restrict function pointer casts. Perhaps some compiler issues a warning.